# Area plot of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

i have the following Dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

it contains a Timestamp as index of the df and two columns, where the first column descriebes the wind direction (S = South, SE = South-East and so on). The second column descriebs the precentage during the Timestamp. EG. South-East with 87.5 % and South with 12.5 % during one entire Day (2018-02-21).

The Area plot shall visualize the precentage of every direction for each day. With the days on the x-axis and the precentage on the Y-axis adding up to a total of 100%.

i do not know how to get my current df to the one i need to be able to visualize my desired graphic.

Any ideas?

The Timestamp still needs to be the Index, but i need a column for each possible Winddirection. The column then shall contain the precantage for each time step of the specific wind direction.

Here is a super abstract drawing only for North, East, South and West direction.

[image]

Comment: do you have an example plot?

Comment: added a drawing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first `.pivot` and then you can plot.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2018-02-21', '2018-02-21', 
                                           '2018-02-22', '2018-02-22', '2018-02-22', 
                                           '2018-02-23', '2018-02-23']),
                   'direction': ['SE', 'S', 'SE', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'SE'],
                   'pct': [87.5, 12.5, 75, 20.8333333, 4.166667, 54.1557, 45.8333]})
```

#### Code

```
df.pivot(index='date', columns='direction', values='pct').fillna(0).plot(kind='area')
```

[image]

Comment: nice. here i was fiddling with groupbys and stackplots, this is a nice way to do it. gotta look into pd.pivot more

Comment: i didnt know this pivot function. Thanks a lot! When i have my index as timestamp, why does df.pivot(df.index, columns='direction', values='pct') does not work?

Comment: @qwertz You can only specify a `column`. So if it is already your index it uses that by default and you don't need to specify it: Try `df.pivot(columns='direction', values='pct').fillna(0).plot(kind='area')`